# Issues with MIN & MAX when using Case statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate a summary report using various aggregate functions: MIN, MAX, SUM, etc.  The issue I have is when I try to get a MIN and MAX of a field when I am also using the case statement.   I am unable to get the MIN value of a field when I am using the case statement.  I can best explain it with sample data and the sql statement:

Fields: AccountNumber, Symbol, TradeDate, TransactionType, Price, Quantity, Amount
Table: Trades

```
AccountNumber, Symbol, TradeDate, TransactionType, Price, Quantity, Amount
123,"XYZ",1/2/2011,"Buy",15,100,1500
123,"XYZ",1/2/2011,"Buy",10,50,500
123,"XYZ",1/2/2011,"Sell",20,100,2000
456,"ABC",1/3/2011,"Buy",10,20,200
456,"ABC",1/3/2011,"Buy",15,30,450
789,"DEF",1/4/2011,"Sell",30,100,3000
```

Query:

```
SELECT AccountNumber,
       Symbol,
       SUM(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then 1 else 0) as TotalBuys,
       SUM(case when TransactionType = "Sell" then 1 else 0) as TotalSells,
       MIN(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then Price else 0) as MinBuy,
       MAX(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then Price else 0) as MaxBuy,
       MIN(case when TransactionType = "Sell" then Price else 0) as MinSell,
       MAX(case when TransactionType = "Sell" then Price else 0) as MaxSell,
       MIN(Price) as MinPrice,
       MAX(Price) as MaxPrice
  FROM Trades
Group By AccountNumber, Symbol
```

What I am expecting is the following results:

```
AccountNumber, Symbol, TotalBuys, TotalSells, MinBuy, MaxBuy, MinSell, MaxSell, MinPrice, MaxPrice
123,"XYZ",2,1,10,15,20,20,10,20
456,"ABC",2,0,10,15,0,0,10,15
789,"DEF",0,1,0,0,30,30,30,30
```

However, I am getting the following results:

```
AccountNumber, Symbol, TotalBuys, TotalSells, MinBuy, MaxBuy, MinSell, MaxSell, MinPrice, MaxPrice
123,"XYZ",2,1,**0**,15,**0**,20,**0**,20
456,"ABC",2,0,10,15,0,0,10,15
789,"DEF",0,1,0,0,30,30,30,30
```

When there are two different TransactionTypes for each grouping, the Min fields (MinBuy,MinSell, and MinPrice) are coming out as 0 as opposed to what is expected.  What am I doing wrong on the sql statement?  Is there another way to get the desired results?

Answer (score 17):

Min between 0 and a positive number is 0, you should change:

```
MIN(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then Price else 0)
```

by

```
MIN(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then Price else Null)
```

Null don't compute in an aggregation function.

Thats all.

**Edited 6 years later**:

As [P5Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239098/p5coder) says, it is enough without `else` clause, also I guess the `end` is mandatory on some database brands. Here it is:

```
MIN(case when TransactionType = "Buy" then Price end)
```

Comment: Syntactical sugar: You can exclude the `else Null` part since by default a `case` statement returns `null` if nothing is specified.

Comment: @P5Coder, thanks! fixed. Sorry about improvement delay ... just  to be consistent between times: answer - comment - improvement ;)